# importance of function wrappers in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

Can someone explain to me the importance of using function wrappers (ie: when assigning onclick functionality)? I know I should, but I don't fully understand why...

Example:
It's my understanding that this:

```
$(callingImg)[0].setAttribute("onclick", "function(){removeChildren(this);}");
```

is better than this:

```
$(callingImg)[0].setAttribute("onclick", "removeChildren(this)");
```

Comment: Just for curiosity can somebody explain me what is a function wrapper?

Comment: the "function(){" and "}" parts

Comment: I don't think you should be using `setAttribute` to assign a click handler to an element. Remember that in JavaScript, you're interacting with the *DOM*, not the HTML. Use `addEventListener` instead (see my comment on @MBO's answer).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of the most common uses of function wrappers is to maintain or lock in that function's context.  For example, if you have some object and you want to use one of it's method's as the `onclick` handler for a given element:

```
someElement.onclick = someObject.someMethod;
```

If `someObject.someMethod` makes any references to `this`, instead of `this` pointing to `someObject` it will instead point to `someElement` because the context has changed.  By wrapping the `someObject.someMethod`

```
someElement.onclick = function() { someObject.someMethod() };
```

you are still executing `someMethod` as a method of `someObject` rather than as a method of `someElement`.

However, if the event handler method never makes any references to `this`, then a wrapper isn't needed.

From the example code that you posted, if you just did

```
$(callingImg)[0].setAttribute("onclick", removeChildren(this));
```

`removeChildren(this)` would be executed immediately and it's return value would be assigned as the `onclick` handler.

---

Here's some sample code to illustrate what's happening

```
var FakeElement = function() {
    this.name    = "FakeElement";
    this.onclick = function() {};
};

var FakeEventHandler = function() {
    this.name = "FakeHandlerObject";
    this.clickHandler = function() {
        console.log("`this` = ", this.name);
    };
};

var e = new FakeElement(); 
var h = new FakeEventHandler();

// Normal usage, `this` points to instance of `h`
console.info("h.clickHandler();");
h.clickHandler();

// Context of this is changed to `e` instead of `h`
console.info("e.onclick = h.clickHandler;");
e.onclick = h.clickHandler;
e.onclick();

// Wrapped to maintain proper context of `this` within `h`
console.info("e.onclick = function() { h.clickHandler(); };");
e.onclick = function() { h.clickHandler(); };
e.onclick();

// Executed immediately and returns `null` causing an error in `e.onclick();`
console.info("e.onclick = h.clickHandler();");
e.onclick = h.clickHandler();
e.onclick();
```

Output:

```
h.clickHandler();
`this` = FakeHandlerObject

e.onclick = h.clickHandler;
`this` = FakeElement

e.onclick = function() { h.clickHandler(); };
`this` = FakeHandlerObject

e.onclick = h.clickHandler();
`this` = FakeHandlerObject
```

---

As a side note, it looks like you're using jQuery.  If that's the case, you can simply do

```
$($(callingImg)[0]).click(function() {
    removeChildren(this);
});
```

better still, if there is always one `callingImg` or you want to apply the same click handler to every `callingImg`, you can just do

```
$(callingImg).click(function() {
    removeChildren(this);
});
```

Comment: In your opinion, would it be better to use $($(callingImg)[0]).click(function() { removeChildren(this); }); or $(callingImg)[0].addEventListener("click", function() { removeChildren(this); }, false);  ?

Comment: I guess the first one uses slightly more JQuery?

Comment: @danwoods: Basically, they both do the same thing. The first one uses a jQuery method and the second uses a native JavaScript method. If you're already using jQuery, use the first—it will deal with cross-browser-messing-around etc....

Comment: @danwoods I agree with @Steve Harrison.  If you're going to use the library, make sure you at least use it for the best parts about it which are, in this case, DOM element selection and cross-browser compatible event handling.  For example, `addEventListener` doesn't work in IE which instead uses `attachEvent` which also implemented and behaves differently.  I highly suggest you stick with the jQuery provided event interface. If for some reason you don't want this, then you'd be best off with just doing `$(callingImg)[0].onclick = function() { ... };`, but again, I don't suggest this.

Answer (score 1):

They're generally used to limit variable scope and guaranteeing that you won't pollute your surrounding scope(s).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(callingImg)[0].setAttribute("onclick", "function(){removeChildren(this);}");
```

That makes no sense. It says: on click, define a function, and do nothing with it.

```
$(callingImg)[0].setAttribute("onclick", "removeChildren(this)");
```

This will work except on IE. **Don't** use `setAttribute` on an HTML document, ever. There are many bugs in `setAttribute` in IE, affecting various attributes including all event handlers. And in general `setAttribute` has no advantage over the shorter, easier-to-read DOM Level 1 HTML properties.

Also it's defining code from a string, something which is widely considered bad practice. It's slower, prone to security problems if you start slinging variables into the string, and may break in the future should Content Security Practice.

More usually, you'd use a function literal:

```
$(callingImg)[0].onclick= function() {
    removeChildren(this);
};
```

However that `$` looks like you're using jQuery, in which case you should use jQuery's own event handling stuff:

```
$(callingImg).click(function() {
    removeChildren(this);
});
```

Comment: Interesting note about `setAttribute`. I usually opt for the more direct approach when setting properties (as you showed in your 3rd code block) so I haven't encountered any of these problems. I have however seen the necessity for `getAttribute`, particularly with the `rel` attribute. I've found that typically `someAnchorNode.rel` returns `null` (unless explicitly set using the method just stated) whereas `someAnchorNode.getAttribute("rel")` returns the expected value. Any thoughts on the cross-browser issues (if any) of `getAttribute`?

Comment: I have no difficulty reading `link.rel` or `a.rel` in IE6–8, Firefox, Opera, Chrome or Safari... test case? The basic issue with get/setAttribute is that IE before version 8 treats `o.getAttribute(x)` as the same thing as `o[x]`, so for attributes whose DOM property name is different to the HTML attribute name, or attributes whose DOM properties are of a different type to `String` (which includes all event handlers which are `Function`), IE will give you the wrong results.

Comment: You know, while trying to recreate this I couldn't come up with anything.  Then I remembered that sometimes I just don't care about standards and I want to embed data in an element without polluting the `class` attribute ... so I'll pollute `rel` instead.  It's in these cases, when using `rel` as an attribute on elements that don't support it in the HTML4/XHTML standard, that this behavior is seen (which will however be supported in HTML5).  Test case: http://jsbin.com/imina/

Comment: Ah OK, you would have to use getAttribute for attributes that simply don't exist in HTML, whether or not they do exist as attributes on a different element. There's no reason to use `rel` here... if you're using your own arbitrary attributes (and it's questionable whether that's a good idea) you should use unambiguous names like `data-mymadeupthing`.

Comment: I completely agree, there is no reason to use rel here. It's not necessarily coddling, but I find that when working with designers and expecting them to populate some attribute with relevant data for some progressive enhancement do-dad, sticking with familiar attribute names makes things easier for them and it's less work that I have to check over. Ultimately, you're probably right about avoiding the naming conflict, but it has severed me well so far.

Answer (score 1):

a very simple set of wrapper functions should be used to isolate the Document Object Model (DOM), from application javascript.  By doing so, you accomplish many things, namely 1) you separate your logic from the user-agent, thereby gaining browser cross-compatibility, and 2) you save yourself a bunch of code in your project.  For instance, ask yourself how many times have you referred to the "document.getElementById()" function?

Why not create a function as follows:

function GE(s){return document.getElementById(s);}

Now, throughout your javascript code, including that contained within your HTML (inline), you change your reference to the new function, removing a bunch of code.

If the W3C changes the access point for functionality for the document.getElementById function, all you need to do is change it in one place.

Additionally, now you can add error trapping and usage counts to the GE() function.

The same can be done for the document.createElement() function.

function CE(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}

In many applications, the very first step should be to isolate the DOM in this manner, creating a 'wrapper' function for each DOM level function to be used.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So you can reuse the functions.

Maybe explain in a little more detail why you are unclear, I'd be happy to help explain.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the uses for function wrappers in this case is so you can do multiple statements within a single event or so you have more control of the argument you're passing in.

If you have no required arguments, you can simply put the name of the function to be called in the event binding.  Otherwise, you can put an inline function(){} into that space to be executed.  I see no reason to put it as a string in the attributes of the elements the way you're doing it.

w/jQuery

```
$( callingImg ).click( aFunctionPointer );
// or if you need arguments
$( callingImg ).click( function( ){ aFunction( someArg ); } );
```

w/Prototype

```
Event.observe( callingImg, 'click', aFunctionPointer );
// or if you need arguments
Event.observe( callingImg, 'click', function( ){ aFunction( someArg ); } );
```

DON'T mix and match these ways, like this

```
$( callingImg ).click( aFunction( ) ); // DON'T DO IT
```

as it will execute aFunction( ) and will use whatever the return value is (unless of course you're returning a function, but I doubt it) as the click event.

Answer (score -1):

Actually it should be

```
$(callingImg)[0].setAttribute("onclick", function(){removeChildren(this);});
```

and

```
$(callingImg)[0].setAttribute("onclick", "removeChildren(this)");
```

First is anonymous function defined inline and will be called after event fires, second is string which needs to be `eval`'ed, which is slower and evil.

Comment: I've been trying to do it the way you've posted (with the function wrapper) but I keep getting a error that says my onclick function looks like: "function () {\n" any ideas why that might be? I'd rather ddo it the most proper way...

Comment: It's not *necessarily* evil in this context, just slow and unnecessary.

Comment: The reason this isn't working is because you're using `setAttribute`. If you're using `setAttribute`, then the second parameter should be a string. Instead, use `addEventListener` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener): `$(callingImg)[0].addEventListener("click", function() { removeChildren(this); }, false);`

Comment: @Steve Harrison `addEventListener` isn't implemented in IE which opens a whole other bag of worms.